# HttpClient GetAsync throws ArgumentNullException using System.Net.Http nuget package

Tags: c#, http, google-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have an issue I cannot seem to fix. I am trying to make a HTTP call to a Google API (https) using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.  However, everytime I run the `GetAsync` line I get the following exception.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Value cannot be null.

I get no stack trace and no exception information other than the message. If I wrap it in a try catch I never catch the exception and the function carries on regardless. But my Debug output is littered with these exceptions.  Here is my code:

```
private async Task<T> MakeRequest<T>(string requestUri)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        // The next line only causes the exception to be thrown
        // Using a try catch doesnt seem to catch the exception
        var request = await client.GetAsync(requestUri);
        var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content, new TolerantEnumConverter2());
        return json;
    }
  }
```

**Update**
I tested this in two projects, one project works fine but the project that uses System.Net.Http nuget package is the one which throws the error

Comment: provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue. I created a quick test and was unable to reproduce the problem. which would mean that information is missing from the original question.

Comment: @Nkosi I did more testing and it only fails when using the System.Net.Http nugetpackage

Answer (score 0):

Please check for Content NULL:

```
if(request.Content != null)
{
    var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content, new TolerantEnumConverter2());
    return json;
}
```